# Isn't "chuckle" the frequentative of "chuck"?

Tags: etymology

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequentative) indicates that the frequentative word "chuckle" has no original form, but [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/chuckle) lists chuckle originating from the third form of chuck, meaning ["to pat or tap lightly, as under the chin"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/chuck).

That seems like a perfectly legitimate original form of chuckle, to me.  So am I missing something, or is Wikipedia missing the mark?

**Edit**
I misread the "chuck<sup>3</sup>" link.  I thought it meant the third sense of first form, marked as "chuck<sup>1</sup> 3.".  But there is actually a "chuck<sup>3</sup>" with a first sense meaning "to cluck".  That's more reasonable!

Comment: *Chuck* also means to throw something carelessly http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/chuck_1?q=chuck

Comment: @Tristan how to you suggest that relates to *chuckle*?

Comment: Jon, I am not suggesting that. bishop mentioned one meaning of the word *chuck* so I just mentioned that it also has another meaning. It is as simple as that.

Comment: @Tristanr: As in, I carelessly chucked this question onto the Internet! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does come from *chuck*, though in the sense of making a noise like a fowl.

Fortunately, wikipedia is easily edited.

Unfortunately, wikipedia is easily edited.

Comment: +1 for giving me a chuckle, chuck! (Actually, I'm *not* a barwoman from the North of England, so I wouldn't normally call anyone except Chuck Norris "Chuck").

Comment: Oh, I didn't even see further down the verb form meaning "to cluck".  I am updating my question in light of this.

Comment: Yes, I see following your link that it directed you to the third from, while you'd followed it to the third sense of the first form. I had just taken your question on faith when I read it.